How to detect pgfkeysnovalue with csname?
To simplify the programming of a package, I want to generate multiple similar commands (\test, \testb, ...) with a single command \NEWCOMMAND. Each key needs to be linked with an unique command name. That name can be automatically generated with \csname. The code in the MWE works fine (inspired by this question), but not for a key without value: [key]. Due to the \csname used in the \edef before \ifdefstring the value changes to empty: [key = {}]. So the \pgfkeysnovalue is stored in \key@test, but doesn't survive the \edef. For \testb the command should be stored in \key@testb.
How can \pgfkeysnovalue be detected in this case?
Remark 1: \ifdefstring{\key@test}{\pgfkeysnovalue} serves only to show that \key@test is correctly defined as \pgfkeysnovalue inside \test. It's not needed in the final code.
Remark 2: An example of the desired behavior of a manually programmed command (e.g. \log) is added at the end. This behavior should be the same when commands are automatically programmed with the single command \NEWCOMMAND. For example the separated control of parentheses for \sin, \cos and \tan. Only \sin[par] should activate this option, other notation deactivates it: \sin[par = {}] or \sin[par = false]. This setup may not affect \cos or \tan.
MWE
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500098/pgfkeys-store-in-constructed-macro
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.store in cs/.code=\pgfkeysalso{%
    \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{##1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\NEWCOMMAND}{m m}{
% Pgfkeys
\pgfkeys{/#2/.cd,
key/.store in cs = key@#2,
key = {}
}
\newcommand{#1}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/#2/.cd, ##1}%
\edef\tempi{\csname key@#2\endcsname}%
text: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{text}{YES}{NO} + %
no value: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{YES}{NO} - %
\ifdefstring{\key@test}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{YES}{NO}% Only to check if \key@test is correctly defined as \pgfkeysnovalue inside \test
\endgroup%
}%
}
\makeatother

\NEWCOMMAND{\test}{test}
\NEWCOMMAND{\testb}{testb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{test}

\verb|key = text| 

\test{key = text}% => YES, NO, NO: true

\verb|key|

\test{key}% => NO, YES, YES: false (once)
\bigskip

\textbf{testb}

\verb|key = text|

\testb{key = text}% => YES, NO, NO: true

\verb|key|

\testb{key}% => NO, YES, NO: false (once)
\end{document}


Example of desired behavior
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%# Logarithm

\makeatletter
% Pgfkeys
\pgfkeys{/logM/.cd,
%
base/.store in = \base@logM,
base = {},
%
par/.store in = \par@logM,
par = {},
%
base front/.store in = \basefront@logM,
base front = {},
%
tikzset/.initial = {},
}

% Command
\RenewDocumentCommand{\log}{O{} m}{
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/logM/.cd, tikzset, #1}
%
\ifdefstring{\par@logM}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{%
    \def\temp@logM{\mleft ( #2 \mright)}
}{%
    \def\temp@logM{#2}
}
%
\ifdefstring{\base@logM}{}{%
    \operatorname{log}\temp@logM
}{%
    \ifdefstring{\basefront@logM}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{%
        \mathop{\displaystyle{}\textsuperscript{\base@logM}\mathrm{log}}\temp@logM
    }{
        \mathop{\displaystyle{}\mathrm{log}\textsubscript{\base@logM}}\temp@logM
    }
}
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathset}{m O{} m}{
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{} = 0
    \tikzset{/#1M/.cd, tikzset = {\pgfkeys{/#1M/.cd, #3}}}
\else
    \tikzset{/#1M/.cd, #2/.initial = {}, #2 = {\pgfkeys{/#1M/.cd, #3}}}
\fi
}

\begin{document}
\mathset{log}{base = a}
$\log{x}$

$\log[par]{\log[par = {}]{x}}$% or \log[par = false]{x} => no parentheses for second log

$\log[base front, base = b]{x}$
\end{document}


Can you add, even in commented form, some code for the case you are trying to solve and what output you would expect from it?

Why do you expect the final test to return NO YES YES rather than NO YES NO? The final part tests whether \key@test is no-value, but you've used \key@testb this time, so \key@test hasn't been defined at all. I get NO YES NO here with a modified version of your test, which is what I'd expect. Could you tell us what you're trying to do with this? Incidentally, you don't need .store in cs. You can just use .store in/.expand once=\csname...\endcsname.

@cfr: You are right, it should be NO YES NO. Otherwise \test would infect \testb, something that needs to be avoided in this setup.

Instead of building some tests to check whether there was a value or not (be it via pgfkeys's \pgfkeysnovalue or L3's \c_novalue_tl) you could as well use a key=value parser which allows you to define different actions for keys that got a value and keys that got none. In expkv there are basically two separate name spaces, one for keys that got values and one for keys without values and you can define different behaviour for the two, even if on the user level they share the same name.
The following defines the NoVal-key to set an internal to \@firstoftwo if it was used (and the value storing cs to empty), whereas the Val-key sets the internal to \@secondoftwo and stores the value.
Otherwise this is pretty much the MWE posted in @cfr's answer.
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \sam@ifeq \tl_if_eq:NnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\protected\long\def\NEWCOMMAND@#1#2#3#4%
  {%
    % #1: \csname sam@key@value@@#3\endcsname
    % #2: \csname sam@key@ifnoval@@#3\endcsname
    % #3: name of NEWCOMMAND
    % #4: set of NEWCOMMAND
    \ekvdefinekeys{sam/#4}%
      {
        % how the key should behave with a value
                 store key = #1
        ,also    code  key = \let#2\@secondoftwo
        % how the key should behave without a value
        ,protect noval key = \let#2\@firstoftwo\let#1\@empty
      }%
    \NewDocumentCommand #3 { m }
      {%
        \begingroup
          \ekvset{sam/#4}{##1}%
          Text: #2{N}{\sam@ifeq#1{text}{Y}{N}}\par
          no value: #2{Y}{N}\par
        \endgroup
      }%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \NEWCOMMAND { m m }
  {%
    \expandafter\NEWCOMMAND@
      \csname sam@key@value@@#2\expandafter\endcsname
      \csname sam@key@ifnoval@@#2\endcsname
      {#1}%
      {#2}%
  }

\NEWCOMMAND{\test}{test}
\NEWCOMMAND{\testb}{testb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{test}

\verb|key = text| 

\test{key=text}% => Y N or N

\verb|key|

\test{key}% => N Y or Y 
\bigskip

\textbf{testb}

\verb|key = text|

\testb{key = text}% => Y N or N    
\verb|key|

\testb{key}% => N Y or Y
\end{document}

Another approach using expkv-cs with a set of internal keys and a layer of user level keys which wrap them up so that all your \NEWCOMMANDs share the same keys. This here provides the keys par, base, and basefront.
Note that the shown approach might get impractical for many keys (in this example there is room for 3 more internal keys before one has to split the output into two macros). But basically the same can be done with storing values inside macros (for instance via expkv-def as in above's code snippet), or with expkv-cs's \ekvcHashAndForward (see the documentation in expkv-bundle.pdf).
As a small aside, the current version of expkv-cs as of writing this (v1.3 2023-01-23) has a limited choice type which is why we use enum and numeric values to denote true and false for basefront and par (upcoming releases of will feature a mechanism for the choice key which will allow to forward macros instead of just the user input).
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}
\newcommand\sam@numboolTF[1]{\if0#1\expandafter\@thirdofthree\fi\@firstoftwo}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\sam@kv\sam@output
  {
    % 
     basefront|internal = 0     % #1
    ,par|internal = 0           % #2
    ,base|noval = \@secondoftwo % #3
    ,base|value = {}            % #4
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\sam@kv
  {
     meta  base = { base|noval = \@secondoftwo, base|value = {#1} }
    ,nmeta base = { base|noval = \@firstoftwo,  base|value = {} }
    ,nmeta basefront = {basefront|internal = 1}
    ,enum  basefront = {basefront|internal}{false, true}
    ,nmeta par = { par|internal = 1 }
    ,enum  par = {par|internal}{false, true}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\mathset{m m}
  {%
    \@ifundefined{sam@defaults@@#1}%
      {\PackageError{sam}{Unknown math set #1}{}}%
      {\expandafter\edef\csname sam@defaults@@#1\endcsname{\unexpanded{#2}}}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\NEWCOMMAND{m m}
  {%
    \expandafter\NEWCOMMAND@\csname sam@defaults@@#2\endcsname{#1}{#2}%
  }
\protected\def\NEWCOMMAND@#1#2#3%
  {%
    \NewDocumentCommand #2 { O{} m }
      {\expandafter\sam@kv\expandafter{#1,##1}{#3}{##2}}%
    \expandafter\let\csname sam@defaults@@#3\endcsname\@empty
  }
\newcommand\sam@output[6]
  {%
    \mathop
      {%
        \sam@numboolTF{#1}{#3{}{{}^{#4}}}{}%
        {\operatorname{#5}}%
        \sam@numboolTF{#1}{}{#3{}{_{#4}}}%
      }%
    \sam@numboolTF{#2}{\mleft(}{}%
    #6%
    \sam@numboolTF{#2}{\mright)}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\NEWCOMMAND\Log{log}
\NEWCOMMAND\Tan{tan}
\NEWCOMMAND\Cos{cos}

\mathset{log}{base=a, basefront, par}
\mathset{cos}{base=b}

\begin{document}
$\Log{5} \cdot \Tan{\alpha} \cdot \Cos{\beta}$

$\Log[base]{5} \cdot \Tan[base=t]{\alpha} \cdot \Cos[basefront=true]{\beta}$
\end{document}



These are innovative and interesting insights for me, clarified with an useful example. The package (originally grown from tikz commands) is based on pgf-keys. Indeed, it is worth considering other methods such as expkv and LaTeX 3. Funny how my name gets in to the code ;)

@Sam well, it's customary to use some prefix to get package-unique names since TeX has no real name spaces. Hence many frequent users use OP's name in their answers for that if no real package is involved.

If you really need to distinguish between key={} and key, I wouldn't use pgfkeys. l3keys provides ready-made items of various kinds which you can use to distinguish such cases. In particular \c_novalue_tl differs from \c_empty_tl and is constructed to differ even from its typeset result, -NoValue-, if compared. Moreover, \tl_if_novalue:nTF is specifically designed to enable user interfaces which need to detect missing optional arguments.
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, border = 5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714697/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_novalue:nTF { v }
\NewDocumentCommand \NEWCOMMAND { m m }{
  \keys_define:nn { sam / #2 }
  {
    key .tl_set:c = { l__sam_key_#2_tl },
    key .default:V = \c_novalue_tl,
    key .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  }
  \NewDocumentCommand #1 { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { sam / #2 } { ##1 }
      Text: ~ \tl_if_eq:cnTF { l__sam_key_#2_tl } { text } { Y } { N }
      ~ + ~ no ~ value: ~ \tl_if_eq:cNTF { l__sam_key_#2_tl } \c_novalue_tl { Y } { N }
      \ ~ or ~ \tl_if_novalue:vTF { l__sam_key_#2_tl } { Y } { N }
    \group_end:
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NEWCOMMAND{\test}{test}
\NEWCOMMAND{\testb}{testb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{test}

\verb|key = text| 

\test{key=text}% => Y N or N

\verb|key|

\test{key}% => N Y or Y 
\bigskip

\textbf{testb}

\verb|key = text|

\testb{key = text}% => Y N or N    
\verb|key|

\testb{key}% => N Y or Y
\end{document}

That is, I would use the method which deals with expansion by letting passing the buck with relief to LaTeX 3.
Answer to Original Question and Edit I
Maybe this helps a little. If I've understood correctly and in the light of discussion in comments, this gives the expected result.
I've used .store in/.expand once=\csname ... \endcsname to avoid the need for defining .store in cs. But, of course, you can use the custom handler if you prefer. I just don't see the benefit in this case as you're wrapping it in a definition anyway.
Rather than test against \pgfkeysnovalue, you can just provide a sufficiently unlikely default and test against that. If you want to test against \pgfkeysnovalue, you'd need to either avoid fully expanding \key@#2 when defining \tempi or test against a full expansion of \pgfkeysnovalue or use a different conditional test. By using some default value, you actually have a string to test against.
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, border = 5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714697/
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\NEWCOMMAND}{m m}{%
  % Pgfkeys
  \pgfkeys{/#2/.cd,
    key/.store in/.expand once = \csname key@#2\endcsname,
    key = {},
    key/.default=XXX,
  }%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \pgfkeys{/#2/.cd, ##1}%
      \edef\tempi{\csname key@#2\endcsname}%
      text: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{text}{YES}{NO} + %
      no value: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{XXX}{YES}{NO} - %
      \ifdefstring{\key@test}{XXX}{YES}{NO}%
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\NEWCOMMAND{\test}{test}
\NEWCOMMAND{\testb}{testb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{test}

\verb|key = text| 

\test{key = text}% => YES, NO, NO:

\verb|key|

\test{key}% => NO, YES, YES:
\bigskip

\textbf{testb}

\verb|key = text|

\testb{key = text}% => YES, NO, NO:     
\verb|key|

\testb{key}% => NO, YES, NO:
\end{document}

Images are a highly annoying problem for me right now, but I get the output commented above (without the question marks etc.).
If you really need to test against \pgfkeysnovalue, you need a different approach. For example,

etoolbox offers alternative conditional tests.
expl3 now offers superior alternatives for most features of etoolbox, but has a steeper learning curve.
An old-fashioned route could test against \edef\tempj{\pgfkeysnovalue} with e.g. \ifx\tempi\tempj ... \else ... \fi. (No good if you need to distinguish an empty value from no value at all.)

EDIT
If you don't need the final test against \key@test, which is awkward because it expands to the same as \pgfkeysnovalue when \testb{key} or \testb{key=<value>} is used, you can handle the test for no value by simply testing against an empty string. For example,
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, border = 5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714697/
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\NEWCOMMAND}{m m}{%
  % Pgfkeys
  \pgfkeys{/#2/.cd,
    key/.store in/.expand once = \csname key@#2\endcsname,
    key = {},
  }%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \pgfkeys{/#2/.cd, ##1}%
      \edef\tempi{\csname key@#2\endcsname}%
      text: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{text}{YES}{NO} + %
      no value: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{}{YES}{NO} - %
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\NEWCOMMAND{\test}{test}
\NEWCOMMAND{\testb}{testb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{test}

\verb|key = text| 

\test{key = text}% => YES, NO, 

\verb|key|

\test{key}% => NO, YES, 
\bigskip

\textbf{testb}

\verb|key = text|

\testb{key = text}% => YES, NO, 

\verb|key|

\testb{key}% => NO, YES, 
\end{document}

Note that you are creating a global default every time you invoke \NEWCOMMAND or, in the terminology of pgfkeys, you are setting an initial value, regardless of the fact you don't use .initial. Because
    key = {},

is not the same as not setting a value. As far as pgfkeys is concerned, it is fairly close because \pgfkeysnovalue expands to the same thing. But, in TeX terms, it is not the same because a macro which expands immediately to nothing is not the same as one which expands immediately to another macro which expands eventually to nothing. I assume this isn't an issue in your case, so just something to be aware of.

The idea of an unlikely default XXX is a good and workable alternative. But \pgfkeynovalue was designed to prevent that a random input like XXX would be considered as no value instead of text. I've removed the default and tried the \ifx, but it fails the test when key is not used: \test{}. Could you give a hint for etoolbox?

@Sam Yes, I realised that and was editing at the same time you were commenting. \pgfkeysnovalue expands to an empty string, which is what you've set key to by default.

@Sam Because you say key = {} globally, you set \key@test to an empty value globally. When you test the value of \key@testb against \key@test, the expansions of these two macros are identical if you used \testb{key}. Is that what you want? Then to distinguish them, you have to control expansion carefully because the fully expanded values really are the same: if you typeset \key@test and \key@testb after \testb{key} then you will get precisely the same result. It's hard to know what might work here without knowing what the goal is.

I've updated the question. The last check (\key@test vs \key@testb) isn't needed in the final code. It was just checking if \key@test is correctly defined as \pgfkeysnovalue.

@Sam In that case, the \ifx\tempi\tempj should work. Just \edef\tempj{} and see if that's the same. Or you can use \ifdefstring{\tempi}{}{YES}{NO}.

That code works for an empty string \test{key = {}} which is not the same as no value \test{key}. A test against \pgfkeysnovalue should make that distinction.

@Sam You're testing with \edef\tempi{\csname key@#2\endcsname}. \tempi is, therefore, exactly the same for \test{key} and \test{key={}}. Add \show\tempi to your code after defining it if you don't believe me. \pgfkeysnovalue expands to zilch. If you really need that distinction, you can't use \tempi.

@Sam See edit. If you really need to distinguish those cases, don't use \edef, Use e.g. expl3 which has e.g. \c_novalue_tl which you can use for the default and test against. This is designed for precisely the kind of case where you need to distinguish no value from an empty one.

Here, I just changed the test:
\ifdefstring{\tempi}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{YES}{NO}

to something more direct, to see if \tempi is empty.
\ifx\tempi\empty YES \else NO \fi

Here is the MWE:
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500098/pgfkeys-store-in-constructed-macro
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.store in cs/.code=\pgfkeysalso{%
    \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{##1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\NEWCOMMAND}{m m}{
% Pgfkeys
\pgfkeys{/#2/.cd,
key/.store in cs = key@#2,
key = {}
}
\newcommand{#1}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/#2/.cd, ##1}%
\edef\tempi{\csname key@#2\endcsname}%
text: \ifdefstring{\tempi}{text}{YES}{NO} + %
no value: 
%REPLACE
%\ifdefstring{\tempi}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{YES}{NO} - %
% WITH:
\ifx\tempi\empty YES \else NO \fi - %
%
\ifdefstring{\key@test}{\pgfkeysnovalue}{YES}{NO}% Only to check if \key@test is correctly defined as \pgfkeysnovalue inside \test
\endgroup%
}%
}
\makeatother

\NEWCOMMAND{\test}{test}
\NEWCOMMAND{\testb}{testb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{test}

\verb|key = text| 

\test{key = text}% => YES, NO, NO: true

\verb|key|

\test{key}% => NO, YES, YES: false (once)
\bigskip

\textbf{testb}

\verb|key = text|

\testb{key = text}% => YES, NO, NO: true

\verb|key|

\testb{key}% => NO, YES, NO: false (once)
\end{document}



This doesn't work because the OP wants to distinguish between key and key= and this test regards both as being no-value cases. That is, the objection will (I assume) be the same as the objection to my \ifdefstring{\tempi}{}{Y}{N}. But this was not at all clear to me from the question :(.

@cfr Thanks for the heads up.  The OP will need to revise the MWE so as to provide a case where that distinction matters.

Indeed ;). I'd like to know what this is really for ....
